# Using webpack to process an AMD library with external dependencies

Tags: javascript, amd, webpack

I have a library written in AMD style that can be used with RequireJS. `jquery` and `jquery-ui` are assumed to be provided by the user of the library. Say it looks like this:

```
// main-lib.js
define(['jquery', './aux-lib.js'], function ($) { ..(1).. });

// aux-lib.js
define(['jquery', 'jquery-ui'], function ($) { ..(2).. });
```

I'm trying to figure out how webpack works. For example, say I want to bundle these files into a single AMD style library file that still assumes `jquery` and `jquery-ui` from the outside:

```
// out.js
define(['jquery', 'jquery-ui'], function ($) { ..(1)..(2).. } );
```

How is this accomplished?

When I run webpack with `main-lib.js` as `entry`-point, it will complain that it can't find `jquery` and `jquery-ui`. If I configure the correct paths with `resolve.alias`, it bundles `jquery` and `jquery-ui` into `out.js`, which is not what I want. I tried using `output.externals` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a pretty simple, stupid mistake on my part. The relevant field is not `output.externals`, but simply `externals`. See [here](http://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html). The other two relevant fields introduced there are inside `output`, but `externals` is not.

PS: `externals` can also be an array. Here is my current configuration:

```
{
    entry: './main-lib.js',
    output: {
        path: './',
        filename: 'out.js',
        libraryTarget: 'amd'
    },
    externals: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui']
}
```

It's working quite nicely.

Comment: So, basically you are just saying "ignore jquery and jquery-ui" then I suppose you're banking on the fact that your code uses the proper names of the global variables (hence why you didn't specify the global variable names here)?

Comment: I'm saying "don't put jquery and jquery-ui in the output library". I'm not banking on global variables at all; the export of jquery is fed through a module parameter. I don't have to know the global variable names, because jquery happens to be AMD aware. If not like this, how would *you* do it?